# Read multiple tables from mySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql

Well i couldn't be really specific about my question in the title so forgive me on that.

I have made a .php script that read's the data from my database and print's it into a table on the page. Basically it should act as banlist. But i am stuck with one problem. Since the ban's are sorted in few different tables in database i need to read all of them for specific detail that i need on banlist. I got most of it done, but i can't get name of the admin who banned the "cheater". Here is how the thing is "admin_id" is located in "penalties" table and the name of admin is located in "clients" table. Now i can't figure out how to get the name of the admin from the "clients" table by "admin_id" from "penalties" table and to print that on same page.

So [this](http://elgc.net/mico/banlist.php) is what i have made and am just missing the "Admin" name.

Here is the code that read's the current info from the database.

```
mysql_query("SELECT penalties.id, penalties.type, penalties.time_add, penalties.time_expire,
                    penalties.reason, penalties.inactive, penalties.duration, penalties.admin_id,
                    target.id as target_id, target.name as target_name, target.ip as target_ip 
             FROM penalties, clients as target 
             WHERE (penalties.type = 'TempBan' OR penalties.type = 'Ban')
                  AND inactive = 0 
                  AND penalties.client_id = target.id
             ORDER BY penalties.id DESC") 
  or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: You need to use a join.

Comment: You want to hear about [mysql JOIN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7877720/the-best-tutorial-on-joins-in-mysql).

Comment: It is recommended to use either the mysqli or PDO_MySQL extensions. It is not recommended to use the old mysql extension for new development. http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Answer (score 1):

This should point you in the right direction:

```
SELECT 
penalties.id, penalties.type, penalties.time_add, penalties.time_expire, penalties.reason, penalties.inactive, penalties.duration, penalties.admin_id, 
clients.id as target_id, clients.name as target_name, clients.ip as target_ip 
FROM penalties 
LEFT JOIN clients
ON penalties.client_id = clients.id 
WHERE (penalties.type = 'TempBan' OR penalties.type = 'Ban')  AND inactive = 0
ORDER BY penalties.id DESC
```

Comment: Wouldn't this only return the cheater's name?

Answer (score 0):

You have two logical joins from penalties back to clients.  therefor you need two joins back.  One for the "Target" one for the "Admin"

```
SELECT penalties.id, penalties.type, penalties.time_add, penalties.time_expire, penalties.reason, 
       penalties.inactive, penalties.duration, penalties.admin_id, target.id as target_id, 
       target.name as target_name, target.ip as target_ip,
       admin.name
FROM penalties, clients as target, clients as admin

WHERE (penalties.type = 'TempBan' OR penalties.type = 'Ban')  
  AND inactive = 0 
  AND penalties.client_id = target.id 
  AND penalties.admin_ID = admin.id

ORDER BY penalties.id DESC
```